# How to run a background service for all the windows users?

Tags: windows, windows-services

I have a background service installed in the Admin account (Say user name is "**X**") on my machine. The machine also has other users. So the installed service is accessible for all.

The problem is when a regular account "**A**" logs in to the machine for the first time, the background service runs on the start up as it should and the Icon appears on the system tray. But when the user locks his account and switches to another account "**B**", the background service doesn't run on the start up. System tray doesn't list the service running icon also. Double clicking on the program icon to launch the service does not do a thing either. I opened up the task manager and it doesn't list the program on its list.

I found out that if i exit the service from the first account and then switch to the next account, the service still does not run on its own. However, now i am able to run the service by double clicking the program icon.

But i need to run the service for the other account automatically when user switches to another account.

**What should i do to run the background service for all the windows account when they are signed in?**

Comment: How have you set up this program to run?

Comment: A “service” is something very specific in Windows. It *cannot* interact with the UI. It runs independent from user logins. What is that you’re really trying to accomplish here?

Comment: My machine has multiple user account. The service was installed from the admin account. Now, whenever the machine is turned on and logged onto an account (doesn't matter which one), the service runs just fine. But when the account is switched (not signing out) to another user, the service doesn't run anymore. But i want to have run the service there in the switched account also. I check the installed list of the second user and the software was installed in the installed software list. But the problem is could not even start the service again by clicking the icon.

Comment: What version of Windows are you using? What you describe (where "A" sees the UI of the service) shouldn't happen in modern versions of Windows: https://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#GUIServices

Comment: That’s why I’ll ask again: Is this a *service* or is it a *background application*? An *application* may simply detect the already running instance and refuse to “run twice”, not noting it’s a different user.